# Does closing the inputstream of a socket also close the socket connection?

Tags: java, api, sockets

In Java API,

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader fromSocket = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter toSocket = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
//do sth with fromSocket ... and close it
fromSocket.close();
//then write to socket again
toSocket.print("is socket connection still available?\r\n");
//close socket
socket.close();
```

In the above code, after I close the InputStream fromSocket, it seems that the socket connection is not available anymore--the client wont receive the "is socket connection still available" message. 
Does that mean that closing the inputstream of a socket also closes the socket itself?

Comment: No, it doesnt throw any exception at the server side. It seems that the toSocket outputstream obj still works at the server side, but at the client side the connection is closed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, closing the input stream closes the socket. You need to use the shutdownInput method on socket, to [close just the input stream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownInput%28%29):

```
//do sth with fromSocket ... and close it 
socket.shutdownInput();
```

Then, you can still send to the output socket

```
//then write to socket again 
toSocket.print("is socket connection still available?\r\n"); 
//close socket 
socket.close();
```

Comment: No, it does a one way shutdown, closing the input half of the socket (so that you cannot receive any more data), but still letting you send your message on the output half, which I thought is what you were asking. When you ultimately call close() on the socket, the output side gets closed as well.

Comment: Yes, closing the input stream closes the socket. Ditto the output stream. So of course what you should close is always the output stream, so It gets flushed.

Comment: I was looking for a way to close the OutputStream without closing the socket and it did the trick!
Thank a lot mate! You ended an interminable quest...

Comment: I am looking for the same @Gregordy but for the `BluetoothSocket`. It doesn't have method `shutdownInput()`. Do you have any idea?