# Socket communication with unknown input length

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am trying to fix a java socket communication bug, where server does not know the input message length. In current situation server test if input finished with `inputStream.available();` method. However this method does not return right answer always. and it causes reading partial input. There seem to be 2 different possibilities to solve this problem.

1. Client should send input size.
2. Client should close its output stream after sending, but it causes client not read response since socket is also closed when output stream is closed.

Are there any other suggestion, especially with help of nio packages ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

to close the output stream of the client.  This will appear as a closed input stream without closing the socket.

BTW: You can't use `socket.getOuputStream().close();` as I though you could.

IMHO sending the length is the best option as this will allow you to send multiple requests using the same socket.

---

Here is an example

```
public class SimpleServerMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(54321);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
            System.out.println("Got " + line);

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        for (String word : "Hello World Bye Bye!".split(" ")) {
            ps.println(word);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SimpleClientMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 54321);
        InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();

        s.getOutputStream().write("Hello\n".getBytes());
        s.shutdownOutput();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
            System.out.println("Got " + line);
        System.out.println("Disconnected.");
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, I have tried closing inputstream on client side but this causes connection close too. Thus after closing inputstream client can not read response since socket closed.

Comment: Closing the output stream doesn't have to close the connection but some libraries may do this.  If they do, it's a bug IMHO.  The socket is not closed until one end closes it.  If you are using a library which closes the socket without your knowledge, I suggest you use another library.

Comment: I am using standart java api of IBM jdk. I think this is the default behaviour. But I will try socket.shutdownInput(). here is the link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956163/does-closing-the-inputstream-of-a-socket-also-close-the-socket-connection

Comment: But you say that socket.getOutputStream().close() closes the socket?

Comment: yes exactly, when client writes its outputstream and close it and then when it tries to read response it gets socket closed exception.

Answer (score 1):

`available()` is not a measure of message length, so there's no reason for it to return a 'right answer' if your definition of 'right answer' is 'message length'.

If you want a message length you have to *send* one. Or else use lines, or a self-describing protocol like XML, Serialization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Imo, sending the input size seems to be the best way to deal with this, but you could also try to define a fixed message length and an ID for every message.

You just need to split your message in parts that are of the size you choose.
When receiving a new message you just check if the id is the same as the previous one. If it is, you append the new message at the end of the first one. If it's not, you can do what you want to do with the message previous message, and start recording a new one.
And every time all the parts of a message have been sent, the client just send a special message to say it's done.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two other methods that are not mentioned that probably should be.

1. Use a special character for denoting the end of a certain input. If there are no new lines allowed in the input the `\r\n` is a choice.
2. Use some sort of serialization - you can send the data as a JSON object or XML or so, then you'll know when there's no more data.