# proper way to close BluetoothSocket

Tags: java, android

I have `gpsSocket` created in such way:

```
final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
final BluetoothDevice gpsDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(bluetoothAddr);
gpsSocket = gpsDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(RFCOMM_UUID);
                gpsSocket.connect();
```

I remove error handling for simplicity.

After that I setup stuff to start work with socket:

```
final InputStream in = gpsSocket.getInputStream();
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "US-ASCII"));
```

If I catch exception during reading from `reader`, should I close `reader`,
or `gpsSocket`, or both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should always take care of closing objects, that are [`Closeable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html)s.

Both [`BluetoothSocket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) and [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) implement `Closeable` interface, which means that as soon as you are done with that object you should take care of disposing from them via calling `close()`, otherwise you'd end up with memory leakage.

The structure should look something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader;

try {
    reader = ... // initialization
} catch (some exception) {
    ...
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

> Should I close *reader*, *gpsSocket*  or both of them?

You certainly should close `reader`. If you no longer need `gpsSocket`, than you should close it also. But as seen in [documentation of BluetoothSocket.close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#close()):

> If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

Comment: But according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956163/does-closing-the-inputstream-of-a-socket-also-close-the-socket-connection closing of stream is closing socket, so `socket.close()` will be no-op, if call before that `stream.close()`, or raise exception, or this is not related answer, because of `BluetoothSocket` different from other sockets?

Comment: Well, it may close, but why should you rely on that? As a lawobedient citizen you took responsibility of creating a `Closeable` object, take care of disposing from it. At the end of the day, maybe `BluetoothSocket` has some other objects that it needs to get disposed of but you don't give him chance to.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#close()): **If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.** Documentation specifies, that you need not close it explicitly.